# How to automatically navigate to another sidebar after data is uploaded in a sidebar within Shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Hello Shiny dashboard experts,

Following reprex works.
i.e. Once the file is uploaded in sidebar: mod1,
we can navigate to sidebar: mod2 and see the uploaded data displayed.

Below is the code:
1. Module to display with its UI
2. Module to read data with its UI
Server and UI for calling modules.

**Can we automate this ?**

**i.e. Once the data is uploaded in sidebar: mod1,**

**sidebar: mod2 should be seen to the user with uploaded data.**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Module UI to read content
mod_readUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  shiny::tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file1"), 
              h3("Choose xlsx file"),
              accept=c(".xlsx")),
    actionButton(ns("ref"), "Refresh")
  )
}

# Server modules of reading content
mod_read <- function(input, output, session){
  # Uploaded data as reactive element
  getData <- reactive({
    req(input$file1) # Ensure file is uploaded
    if(!is.null(input$file1)){
      my_data <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath)
      my_data
    }
    else{
      my_data <- "nothing" %>% as.data.frame()
      my_data
    }
  })

  ### In order to pass data as reactive elements to other module:
  # Created list
  reactive({
    # browser()
    list("excl" = getData())
  })
}

# Module UI to display content
mod_displayUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  shiny::tagList(
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns("contents"))
  )
}

# Server functions
mod_display <- function(input, output, session, file) {
  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(file())
    DT::datatable(file()$excl,
                  options = list(pageLength = 7,scrollX = TRUE))
  })
}


ui <- 
  shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
    shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(),
    shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
      shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(id = "menu1",
                                  shinydashboard::menuItem('mod1',
                                                           tabName = 'mod1', 
                                                           icon = shiny::icon('file')),

                                  shinydashboard::menuItem('mod2',
                                                           tabName = 'mod2', 
                                                           icon = shiny::icon('file'))
      )),
    shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
      shinydashboard::tabItems(
        shinydashboard::tabItem("mod1",
                                mod_readUI("sidemod1")),
        shinydashboard::tabItem("mod2",
                                mod_displayUI("bodymod2")
        )
      )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  # storing mod_read in a variable
  readFile1 <- shiny::callModule(mod_read, "sidemod1")
  # passing the output of readFile into mod_display module
  displayFile <- shiny::callModule(mod_display, "bodymod2", file = readFile1)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can add an `observe` to see when the `sidemod1-file1` `input` is not `NULL` or changes. When that happens, you can use `updateTabItems`. Note you need to have `session` as a `server` function argument as well.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # storing mod_read in a variable
  readFile1 <- shiny::callModule(mod_read, "sidemod1")
  # passing the output of readFile into mod_display module
  displayFile <- shiny::callModule(mod_display, "bodymod2", file = readFile1)

  observe({
    req(input$`sidemod1-file1`)
    updateTabItems(session, "menu1", "mod2")
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, I replaced server function with yours. Also, 
```  
library(shinydashboard)
  choice <- reactive({
         input$sel})
  ``` But there is an error: **Warning: Error in choice: argument "choice" is missing, with no default
  [No stack trace available]** when uploaded a file

Comment: @Abhi - I'm confused. First, were you able to confirm the behavior works with my `server` code and your `ui` code combined? It works for me. Second, as for the additional code `choice <- reactive ({ input$sel })` I don't see an input with that name of "sel", and I don't see `choice` used anywhere. Perhaps the code you are using is different than what was posted? I would need your revised code to better understand what the error is about. Let me know if I'm missing something else.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I had few more features in my original code. But yes, your code works.